# Is it best to slice roast meat if eating the next day?

Tags: chicken, pork, roast, roast-beef

So I have just roasted a chicken, a lump of beef (not sure which cut) and some pork shoulder.

We will be eating the meat over the next few days.

Would it be best to slice the meat now (after resting), or leave it uncut until just before eating?

Comment: Cut meat only before consuming.  Cutting => increasing surface area => shortening its shelf file, making it dry out fast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave it uncut, if you slice it now your slices will dry out more.

Comment: Makes sense, but what about if I sliced it and left the slices to sit in it's juices? There was quite a lot of juice from roasting three lots of meat. I have experimentally sliced up the pork and covered it in the juices. Could the increased surface area allow the pork to now absorb more juice and thus be more moist?

Comment: Sitting in its own juices should keep it from drying out, but it won't make it more moist through absorption.

Answer (score 3):

The meat will slice better if chilled first. Just put it in the fridge and slice when you want. I often find myself looking for a better way as I always like it better when fresh cooked and still warm, but that has always been an obstacle as you only eat a certain amount. Then the rest is left. Ticket is that meat will always slice easier when cold.